# nginx forwarding to a different port

Tags: nginx, proxy

Alright so I'm using nginx to forward communication to and from my server and clients. My server receives the communication via port 6543, and nginx forwards it to that port on that server (from port 80 on the nginx proxy server)

It works fine if I enter `http://mydomain.com/directory/` <- note the trailing slash

but if i enter `http://mydomain.com/directory` <- no trailing slash

it becomes `http://mydomain.com:6543/directory/` which of course doesn't work, because the nginx server isn't expecting anything on that port.

I can't figure out how to fix this. Help?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post your nginx configuration.

Comment: I don't think that's going to help with only 8 views, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [port_in_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect) to off on the back-end server use [proxy_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) on the front-end server.

Comment: Man I am failing so terribly.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to rewrite your application to redirect to a different port than the one it thinks it's using.

Also, some proxy/caching servers do have utilities for stripping a port number from a redirect. Yet I don't recall NGINX having this.